# Python and ftplib, unable to login?

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

I'm learning Python and I tried using the FTPLib module for Python with this code:

```
import ftplib

connect = ftplib.FTP('ftp://www.website.com')
connect.login = ('username', 'password')
data = []
connect.dir(data.append)
connect.quit()
for line in data:
    print line
```

(I'm aware that the website, username and password is incorrect, I used my website data which I don't want to share) I received the following error after running the code:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ftp.py", line 3, in <module>
    ftp = FTP('ftp://www.website.com')   # connect to host, default port
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.connect(host)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 135, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Just to clarify, I'm using Python 2.7 on a Mac. I don't think there is anymore details I could share. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not 100 % sure, but it might be complaining because you've added ``ftp://`` in the address, which isn't needed because it'll always use the ftp protocol. The error you're getting means that the computer cannot find an ip matching the host you've entered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Joel Hinz, I just needed to remove 'ftp://' from my hostname. Thanks!